# JavaScript IF..ELSE Conditions not outputting expected value

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am working through the [tutorials for Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/). I was testing out the `Boolean()` function and the If...Else conditions.

I have a single button on a website. When I click the button it displays the current state of a boolean variable (`myvar`) and also the corresponding state (`myvartxt`) (ie. `false` means "OFF", `true` means "ON"). The reason for this is because I want to, later on, toggle an LED ON/OFF and don't want it to say false/true but rather ON/OFF.

Now the problem is when I click the button the state of the boolean (myvar) is false which is correct, BUT the myvartxt variable is ON when it should say OFF. I just don't understand. Any ideas? Thanks for your help in advance!

Test out code quickly [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tostring_boolean):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
    //Initial state
    var myvar=new Boolean(0);
    var myvartxt = "OFF";

    //display current state of Boolean
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML=myvar.toString();

    //display corresponding ON -> true, OFF -> false
    if (myvar) //INITIALLY THIS IS false (not a string) so why does it think this is true?
    {
        myvartxt = "ON"; 
    }
    else
    {
        myvartxt = "OFF";
    }

    var y=document.getElementById("demo1");
    y.innerHTML=myvartxt;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should also add that when I explicitly put the condition: if (myvar == true) then it works as expected.

Comment: First, stop learning from w3schools, as their information is often misguided. So bad that some great front end developers made http://w3fools.com/. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new object with `new Boolean()`; and objects in JavaScript evaluate to `true`.

I think if you drop the `new` keyword and use `Boolean()` simply as a function, you'll see behavior more in line with what you expect.

Comment: Check out a good write up on this here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/. Also, you never need to use `Boolean()`. Just use `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you! That article had my exact problem and explained it well.

Answer (score 0):

the code `if (myvar)` is wrong, it simple checks if `myvar` is set. you have to change the statement

```
if (myvar.toString() == true)
```

Comment: Yes, if I explicitly check if myvar == true this works as well. I now know that objects in JavaScript evaluate to true which was the real problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/)

This could be rewritten like this:

```
// Perform logic when document is set and ready.
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var myvar = false; // No need for Boolean objects.
  $("demo").html(myvar.toString()); // Set the value of demo.
  myvar ? $("demo1").html("ON") : $("demo1").html("OFF"); // True/false ON/OFF in demo1
}
```

Also, JavaScript is nasty for equality testing, have a look [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/03/quality-equality-with-javascript-quotquot-gt-quotquot.aspx), and if you get the chance, read [this](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do).

Comment: I really like the line: myvar ? $("demo1").html("ON") : $("demo1").html("OFF"); Really cuts down on my if..else statements to toggle. Thanks!